# Нужна ли запятая или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

**Я улыбаюсь не менее(,) чем среднестатистический человек?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Не менее" в данном случае неуместно. Лучше сказать "Я улыбаюсь не реже, чем среднестатистический человек". Запятая нужна перед подчинительным союзом *чем*.